# Recreate the Oracle DUAL table

Tags: oracle, dual-table

Is there any way to create / recreate dual table in Oracle? It was accidentally dropped.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably contact Oracle Support.

Do you have a backup? If so, restore the table from your backup. Otherwise (and if contacting Oracle is not an option for you)...

Oracle has special optimizations for DUAL, but I don't know if there's anything special about the table itself. I would just treat it like a normal table and see what happens. Try this:

Connect as SYSDBA and then execute these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE SYS.DUAL
(
  DUMMY  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO SYS.DUAL VALUES ( 'X' );

COMMIT;

GRANT SELECT ON SYS.DUAL TO public WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM DUAL FOR SYS.DUAL;
```

And never EVER change ANYTHING in the SYS schema again!

EDIT: Just noticed a duplicate from TODAY: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816478/recovering-dual-table-in-oracle - added suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle becomes weird if `DUAL` is dropped accidentally.

SQLPlus says `SP2-0575: Use of Oracle SQL feature not in SQL92 Entry Level.` if there's no `sys.DUAL` or the current user has no privilege to select from it.

It feels like oracle determine version-related features according to `DUAL`.

Answer (score -1):

Dual Table is a dummy table in system tablespace. As a user, u dont have right to drop it. if you have your own dual table in your schema, u can play around it. U can perform dml, drop it, truncate it etc. Even if u drop, u can recreate it again from the same scripts as previous.