# Problema trying to recreate synonym DUAL

Tags: oracle, synonym, recreate

In this link [How to recreate public synonym "DUAL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504918/how-to-recreate-public-synonym-dual) I've the same problem with one diference.

I executed this comand: CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM "DUAL" FOR "DUAL"

CREATING SO A "LOOPING CHAIN OF SYNONYMS". SO A REMOVE THE SYNONYM.

NOW MY PROBLEMA IS: The SCHEMA "exemple" can't connect in DUAL. (select * from dual) only can doing (select * from sys.dual).

We are trying to recreting the SYNONYMS but nothing are working. 
Someone can help me?

Comment: With which user did you run the command?

Comment: take at look at this post it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504918/how-to-recreate-public-synonym-dual